# sp_BlitzWho Does Not Complete

Tags: sql-server

Just trying out `sp_BlitzWho` for the first time.  On one specific server it never completes but continues to consume CPU, as observed via `sp_whoisactive`.

I have played with the SQL generated and isolated it down to the "blocked" outer apply.  If I comment out the WHERE clause in the "blocked" outer apply it completes.  Or if I only execute either of the conditions in the WHERE it completes.

```
WHERE (s.session_id = sys2.spid
   OR s.session_id = sys2.blocked)
```

I don't really know how to take this further.  I did consider 2 outer applies rather then the one with the OR in the WHERE.

I am running `sp_BlitzWho Version = '5.2'; VersionDate = '20170406'`.

As Brent pointed out, this is not the current version from GitHub.

Comment: What's the exact version number you're using?

Comment: Version = '5.2';
VersionDate = '20170406';

Comment: That's not the latest and greatest version, sir, and that was fixed in the current version.

Comment: It is the one included with the direct link from the FRK kit email yesterday afternoon.  I will try and find latest.

Comment: Grabbed it from GitHub and all good.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that's the older version. We released a [new one](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/master/sp_BlitzWho.sql) a couple days ago that has a performance improvement for that query.

The join in the new code should look like this (as well as use a table variable (I know, I know), and also `READ UNCOMMITTED`):

```
WHERE (s.session_id = b.session_id
OR s.session_id = b.blocking_session_id)
```

The newer version should complete in roughly the same time as the lovely and talented sp_WhoIsActive.

[image: Nuts]